# Why do I get the error "Handlebars error: Could not find property 'bind-attr' on object"

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm working through the [getting started guide for Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/displaying-a-models-completeness/) and as instructed am using the following template code:

```
<li {{bind-attr class="isCompleted:completed"}}>
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
  <label>{{title}}</label><button class="destroy"></button>
</li>
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: <(subclass of Ember._MetamorphView):ember316> Handlebars error: Could not find property 'bind-attr' on object <Todos.Todo:ember303:1>.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using an outdated version of ember, `bind-attr` was introduced today in 1.0.0.rc8.
`bindAttr` is now deprecated so you should realy use `bind-attr`